# Invalid octal format encountered in function passing parameter

Tags: c++, visual-c++

### In main.cpp

```
classObject.sendTime(23,10,08);
```

### In class.cpp

```
void CClassName::sendTime(unsigned short hh, unsigned short mm, unsigned short ss)
{//some operation}
```

In main.cpp the line get an error "Invalid octal format encountered"

In case of classObject.sendTime(10,05,02); the code compiles and executes.

What could be a possible reason for this? Please help

Answer (score 7):

Any integer literal starting with digit `0` followed by other digits is considered to be octal, i.e. base 8. The digits following the `0` must be valid octal digits, which excludes `08`, since the only valid digits in base 8 are **[0,7]**. Just use `8`.

See [this reference for octal and other integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Comment: Except when it is followed by `x` (hexadecimal).

Comment: @Andrey I re-phrased and added a helpful reference.

Comment: @Andrey: `x` isn't typically considered a "digit".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to be fair, my answer didn't specify "digits" before Andrey's comment.